# Laplace of a function raised to a power

Tags: laplace-transform

For example:

$y' = y + y^2$

The Laplace of the first two terms is $s(F(s)-f(0))$ and $F(s)$.

But what is the Laplace of $y^2$?

Comment: The Laplace transform isn't very nice with nonlinear things. In particular, the Laplace transform of $y^2$ is the convolution of $Y$ with itself. This turns your differential equation into an integral equation which is probably harder to solve than the original differential equation.

Comment: The multiplication of two functions is transformed into the convolution of the transformed functions, i.e. $\mathcal{L}(f(x) \cdot g(x)) = F(s) \ast G(s)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems, "Multiplication")

Comment: To solve this, I'd separate variables like this: $$\frac{dy}{y(y+1)} = dx.$$ Then I would use partial fractions: $$ \left( \frac 1 y - \frac 1 {y+1} \right) dy=dx.$$ Then integrate both sides. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

As Ian has pointed out, it is hard to deal with the laplace transform of the equation. You can solve the equation in this way:

$$\frac{y'}y =y+1$$

$$\ln (|y|)=\int y\,dx +x $$

Again

$$\frac{y'}{y+1}=y$$

$$\ln(|y+1|) = \int y \,dx$$

So
by taking the difference:

$$\ln \left( |\frac y{y+1}| \right) = x+C$$

$$\frac y{y+1} =\pm k e^x$$

$$y=\frac 1{1 \mp ke^x} -1= \frac{\pm ke^x}{1 \mp ke^x}$$

Comment: Minor point: $y=0$ and $y=-1$ are stationary solutions which are missed by your method. A somewhat more major point: the "standard" technique here would have been separation of variables: $\int \frac{dy}{y+y^2} = x+C$ and then the left side can be computed using partial fractions.

Comment: @Ian Yea you are right that my method isn't standard. I haven't received formal classes so my work isn't fully rigorous. I am just posting what I figured out. Anyway I will take notes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help. The partial fraction method makes the most sense.

I found out that what I posted was a particular case of Bernoulli equation, which you might find interesting.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx

We can make the substitution

$$v=1/y$$

Then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx} = -v^{-2}\frac{dv}{dx}$$

The original equation becomes

$$-v^{-2}\frac{dv}{dx} = v^{-1} + v^{-2}$$

Divide by ($-v^{-2}$), multiply by $e^x$ and integrate,

$$e^xv' + e^xv = -e^x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big[e^xv\big] = -e^x$$
$$v = -e^{-x}\int e^xdx$$
$$v = -1 + ce^{-x}$$

Substitute back to $y$

$$y = \frac{1}{ce^{-x}-1} = \frac{e^x}{c-e^x}$$