# Laplace Transform of $y^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

When the Laplace transform of $y$ is denoted $Y(s)$, we have formulas for the derivatives of $y$ without actually knowing what $y$ is. Is there an explicit formula for $y^2$? More generally, $y^n$?

Comment: Do you just want the laplace transform of a basic power function, or a something like $y(x)^2$, where it's an entire function taken to a power?

Comment: The entire function taken to a power - sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Generally, no..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790582/laplace-of-a-function-raised-to-a-power) math stackexchange link, it seems there's no quick and easy way to do it. From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) on Laplace transform, it lists how to calculate $\mathcal{L}(f(t)g(t))$, in which case you could simply say $f(t)=g(t)$. But the formula deals with the convolution of two functions, namely

$$\mathcal{L}(f(t)g(t))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}F(\sigma)G(s-\sigma)d\,\sigma$$

And this integration is done along the vertical line $\textrm{Re}(\sigma)=c$, where $F(\sigma)$ and $G(s-\sigma)$ are the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, respectively. So it's clear that for an arbitrary function, taking the laplace of $f(t)^n$ is not an easy task.